# Are questions about the nature, scope, and limits of academia reasonable on Philosophy.SE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

For instance, I would consider the question "[can people still be world class scholars in more than one field](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/48066/can-people-still-be-world-class-scholars-in-more-than-one-field)" a valid question, essentially falling into "philosophy of academics."

Comment: Here is my answer on the validity of "Philosophy of Academia" https://www.reddit.com/r/philosophy/comments/7mu3z5/philosophy_of_academia/

Comment: Can you unpack this a little bit? Even one or two more sentences here might help